# Adding arrays of hashes and sort by hash value

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays

```
arrayOne = [{:name=>"name1", :id=>1}, {:name=>"name2", :id=>2}, {:name=>"name3", :id=>3}]

arrayTwo = [{:name=>"name2.1", :id=>1}, {:name=>"name2.2", :id=>2}, {:name=>"name2.3", :id=>3}]
```

And I want to flatten and sort these two arrays into one big array so I tried this

```
@bigArray = [arrayOne, arrayTwo].flatten.sort {|a,b| a.name <=> b.name}
```

However this does not work. I am new to rails and am unsure about the above `flatten.sort` should it be mapped?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Define "doesn't work"

Comment: Why are you reassigning `arrayOne`?

Comment: Also use `a[:name] <=> b[:name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(arrayOne + arrayTwo).sort_by { |e| e[:name] }
#=> [{:name=>"name2.1", :id=>1},
#    {:name=>"name2.1", :id=>1},
#    {:name=>"name2.2", :id=>2},
#    {:name=>"name2.2", :id=>2},
#    {:name=>"name2.3", :id=>3},
#    {:name=>"name2.3", :id=>3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the ruby syntax to access hash members is `hash[key]` rather than `hash.key`.

Secondly, since both of `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` are arrays, you can just use the `+` operator on them and then do the sort. There's no need to make an intermediate array and then do a flatten.

Write it as:

```
bigArray = (arrayOne + arrayTwo).sort_by { |el| el[:name] }
```

Comment: I see that changing the bigArray to reflect a[:name] <=> b[:name] works, but I like (arrayOne + arrayTwo).sort_by { |e| e[:name] } better in terms of understanding, coming from php it makes sense to me